# How to join second elements in tuples using group by first element python

Tags: python, string, join, tuples

I have a list of tuples

```
a = [('name', 'color'),('fruit', 'color'),('thing', 'type'),('sport', 'type')]
```

I want to join first elements grouped by second element. The output should look like.

```
a = [('name fruit', 'color'),('thing sport', 'type')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `dict` with the key that you want to group and add value to `list` base `key`. For this approach, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or if you don't want to import anything you can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault).

```
from collections import defaultdict


a = [('name', 'color'),('fruit', 'color'),('thing', 'type'),('sport', 'type')]
res = defaultdict(list)
res_2 = {}

for tpl in a:
    res[tpl[1]].append(tpl[0])
    res_2.setdefault(tpl[1], []).append(tpl[0])

# Now you can use `res_2` instead of `res`
lst = [(' '.join(v), k) for k,v  in res.items()]
print(lst)
```

Another option can be to use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). For this approach, you can set with which value of your `tuple` you want to group. *(Because you want to group the base second value of each tuple you can set the key of `groupby` like `lambda x: x[1]`.)*

```
from itertools import groupby

res = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(a, lambda x: x[1]):
    res.append((' '.join(tpl[0] for tpl in group), key))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[('name fruit', 'color'), ('thing sport', 'type')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in a *list comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

my_list = [('name', 'color'),('fruit', 'color'),('thing', 'type'),('sport', 'type')]

new_list = [(' '.join(item[0] for item in g_list), x) for x, g_list in groupby(my_list, itemgetter(1))] 

#   where `new_list` will be holding the value:
#       [('name fruit', 'color'), ('thing sport', 'type')]
```

Answer (score 0):

No imports needed by probably not super fast:

```
new = [(a[k][0] + " " + a[k+1][0], a[k][1]) for k in range(0, len(a), 2)]
```